# Help transforming a sentence from pasive voice to active voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I have trouble using the active voice on some sentences. For example,

The IOS version of the game will be developed using Swift.

I know that the verb is developed and the subject is Swift, but I can't rearrange the sentence to active voice.

I would appreciate any gudlines to help me convert these types of sentences to active voice.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to make some logical inference about who is doing the action. For example if the passive voice version were "Three goals were scored in the second period", you might change it to "The players scored three goals in the second period". Even though the person doing it isn't explicitly stated, you can make a logical guess about who they were due to the nature of the action being done.

Comment: @ThePhoton that's what I was missing. I need to make an inference. This answers my question

Comment: @ThePhoton can put that in an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Swift is not the subject. In fact, subject is hidden here.  Thus, you can change it to active voice with an assumed subject, like X will develop the IOS version of the game using Swift. Or, Using Swift, X will develop the IOS version of the game.

Comment: @RamPillai thanks, I realized that shortly after I was told to make in inference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real subject is buried in the passive verb:

"Developers of the iOS version will use Swift."

Or, if you need to be very explicit:

"Programmers will develop the iOS version of the game using Swift."

Or, if you need to sound very corporate:

"Team iOS will use Swift." :)

Comment: The subject buried in the passive verb is the solution i was looking for. I'll try to spot that pattern on other passive sentences.